# Instance normalization in coreml

Tags: ios, keras, coreml, coremltools

I want use Instance Normalization in a converted model (Keras to CoreML).

Keras contrib Instance Normalization is treated as custom layer in coreML. So I copied custom layer like this.

```
    def create_instance_normalization_spec(layer):

       input_name = layer._inbound_nodes[0].inbound_layers[0].name
       input_name += '_output'
       output_name = layer.name + '_output'


       spec_layer = NeuralNetwork_pb2.NeuralNetworkLayer()
       spec_layer.name = layer.name
       spec_layer.input.append(input_name)
       spec_layer.output.append(output_name)


       spec_layer_params = spec_layer.batchnorm


       weights = layer.get_weights()
       channels = weights[0].shape[0]

       idx = 0
       gamma, beta = None, None
       if layer.scale:
           gamma = weights[idx]
           idx += 1
       if layer.center:
           beta = weights[idx]
           idx += 1

       epsilon = layer.epsilon or 1e-5

       spec_layer_params.channels = channels
       spec_layer_params.gamma.floatValue.extend(map(float, 
gamma.flatten()))
       spec_layer_params.beta.floatValue.extend(map(float, 
beta.flatten()))
       spec_layer_params.epsilon = epsilon
       spec_layer_params.computeMeanVar = True
       spec_layer_params.instanceNormalization = True
```

```
instance_norm_spec = 
create_instance_normalization_spec(keras_model.layers[-1])
instance_norm_spec.input[:] = ["input1"]
instance_norm_spec.output[:] = ["output1"]
mlmodel._spec.neuralNetwork.layers[-1].CopyFrom(instance_norm_spec)
```

Now, this coreML model can predict.But outputs are wrong.
Is the way above wrong? How can I fix it?

Comment: It is possible the Keras version of instance normalization does a different computation than the Core ML version. You'd have to look at the documentation or source code of the Keras version and the comments in NeuralNetwork.proto in coremltools to see if they compute the same thing.

Comment: wow. I'm using your CoreML Helper. I check difference between keras and coreML. Thank you very much!!